# "google play services are updating" in emulator

Tags: android, google-maps

i just installed the google play services SDK yesterday. this is what happens when i start a new google maps application in a new emulator(see screenshot). it stays stuck on this screen for hours. if i shut down the emulator and restart it, the app crashes at startup. the logcats also give me an error about a module failing to load. the error is also in the screenshot.

```
06-28 16:35:29.101 2956-2956/? W/DynamiteUtils: Failed to load module: 
module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite not found
06-28 16:35:29.101 2956-2956/? W/DynamiteUtils: Attempt 1 failed.
06-28 16:35:29.223 2956-2956/? W/DynamiteUtils: Failed to load module: 
module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite not found
06-28 16:35:29.223 2956-2956/? W/DynamiteUtils: Attempt 2 failed.
06-28 16:35:29.340 2956-2956/? W/DynamiteUtils: Failed to load module: 
module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite not found
06-28 16:35:29.340 2956-2956/? W/DynamiteUtils: Attempt 3 failed.
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6toi.jpg

any suggestions?

Comment: try an actual device. AFAIK you cannot run this API on emulator.

Comment: @android_Muncher it works on a device. thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nexus 5 and Nexus 5X emulators. They have Play Store, and  let you play with play services without headache.
[image]

Comment: tried both. same thing happens. but this time, i get this error...E/ChimeraCfgMgr: Failed to read module config: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_config.pb (No such file or directory)