# Android Emulator stuck on "Google Play Services are Updating"

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, google-play, google-play-services

I recently began learning how to create Google Maps activities in Android app development, and have stumbled onto an issue with Google Play Services.  Whenever I set my gradle build dependency to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'`, which is the most recent version of `play-services-maps`, the emulator screen gets stuck on the following view upon running my maps app:

[image: Google Play services are updating]

I have allowed the app to sit there for over an hour, and nothing has changed or updated.  As I've read in other StackOverflow questions, I can get the app to properly function by setting my gradle build dependency to an older version, such as `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'`, but this limits my ability to use newer Android features and APIs in my apps, such as FusedLocationProviderClient.

I am running on Nougat 7.1.1, and have installed the following SDKs in an attempt to solve this Google Play Updating issue:

- Android SDK Build-Tools
- Android SDK Tools
- Google Play APK Expansion Library
- Google Play services
- Support Repository > Google Repository

I haven't found any StackOverflow threads specific to this "Google Play services are updating" message.  What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use API 24 or API 26 Android Emulator system images and you should be good to go. API 25 does not have the latest Google Play Store app pre-installed yet.  Note on the screen shot that only these images are "Google Play" versions.

[image: Android Studio 3.0 AVD Manager - System Image Selection]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jamal Eason's answer, you may use Nexus 5 and Nexus 5X emulators which have Play Store. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813113/google-play-services-are-updating-in-emulator). You may also [try running on real android device](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-google-maps-for-android-basics--cms-24635) connected via USB that supports google maps and having google play service installed.